# How to pass a control-sequence as an argument to a macro that expects whitespace after the argument?

Tags: macros, tex-core

Consider the following macro definition:

```
\def\mac#1 .{}
```

Is there a way to pass `\mac` a control-sequence as an argument? I don't see how it can be done, because the TeX scanner will "swallow" all whitespace after the control-sequence, and the TeX "core" won't be aware that there once was whitespace there.

For instance, the following attempt:

```
\def\mac#1 .{}%
\mac\relax .%
\bye
```

results in the error message:

```
Runaway argument?
\relax .
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \mac.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<to be read again> 
                   \bye 
l.3 \bye
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can surround the argument by braces. Those braces will not become part of the argument:

```
\def\mac#1 .{\message{[[#1]]}}%
\mac{\relax} .%
\bye
```

Answer (score 4):

Applying an empty group `{}` after the macro will allow the subsequent space to be recognized.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\mac#1 .{\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}
\begin{document}
\mac\relax{} .
\end{document}
```

As Harald notes, the empty group will, however, be part of the argument here.

[image]

Here's a way to avoid the empty group

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\def\mac#1 .{\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}
\begin{document}
\expandafter\mac\expandafter\relax\space.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is `\mac`'s argument?

Comment: Won't that include the braces in the argument? I think `\mac{\relax} .` is the correct answer.

Comment: @EvanAad Oops.  I wasn't thinking of the argument (I revised)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen My mistake. I have revised.  But yes, the empty braces will be included in the argument.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I have provided an alternative that avoids the empty group.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in plain TeX?

Comment: @EvanAad The essense of this answer depends in no way on LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

You have to tokenize in the correct order, for example

```
\def\mac#1 .{}%
\long\def\firstofone#1{#1}
\firstofone{\mac\relax} .%
\bye
```